# React useEffect dependencies for subscribe/unsubscribe with eslint exhaustive-deps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, react-hooks

I have a `useEffect` hook that should subscribe to geolocation updates when the component appears, and then unsubscribe when the component disappears. So I pass `[]` as the effect dependencies since I only want this to run on mount/unmount.

```
import { useWatchPosition } from "@ionic/react-hooks/geolocation"
import React, { useEffect } from "react"

function SiteMap() {
  const { currentPosition, startWatch, clearWatch } = useWatchPosition()

  // Subscribe/Unsubscribe to geo location on component mount/unmount.
  useEffect(() => {
    startWatch()
    return clearWatch
  }, [])

  return <svg>{/* ... */}</svg>
}
```

Which causes eslint to warn:

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: `clearWatch` and `startWatch`. Either include them or remove the dependency `array.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)`

So I changed it to this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    startWatch()
    return clearWatch
  }, [startWatch, clearWatch])
```

Which causes an infinite render loop.

I'm guessing the infinite loop is caused by the `@ionic/react-hooks/geolocation` library which is creating new functions every time `useWatchPosition()` is called, making the dependencies look stale.

So should I just disable the check for this line via:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Or is there some way I'm missing to do the right thing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading the `useWatchPosition` [source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-react-hooks/blob/master/src/geolocation/useGeolocation.ts), you can see that the functions are not created with `useCallback`, this means that they are regenerated whenever the hook is called.

You can store a reference to the functions in a `ref`, and use the `ref.current` to call the function:

```
function SiteMap() {
  const { currentPosition, startWatch, clearWatch } = useWatchPosition()
  
  const startWatchRef = useRef(startWatch)
  const clearWatchRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    clearWatch.current = clearWatch // the updated clearWatch
  })

  // Subscribe/Unsubscribe to geo location on component mount/unmount.
  useEffect(() => {
    startWatchRef.current()
            
    return () => clearWatchRef.current()
  }, [])

  return <svg>{/* ... */}</svg>
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that call `clearWatch` immediately after every render, but never call `startWatch` more than once?

Comment: Nope, since `clearWatch` is returned as the function that will be called when the component unmounts. It's returned without being called - `return clearWatch`.

Comment: Wait, I thought effect cleanup function would be called anytime the dependencies change _or_ it unmounts. The cleanup function will only get called on unmount?

Comment: You're right. It will be called on every rerender in this case. I've updated the answer. Note that since refs are known to be static you don't even need to include them in the dependencies list (although including them won't matter).

Comment: Update - the `clearWatch` function should contain the updated `watchId` after `startWatch` is called, and sets the `watchId`, so you should update the `clearWatchRef.current` whenever the component rerenders. Don't call `startWatch` more than once in the component.